# How to find the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/2}+5^{1/3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How would I find this polynomial algebraically?

For example, if I wanted to find the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, I would set $\alpha=3^{1/2}$, square both sides, and substract by $3$ to yield $\alpha^2-3=0$.

How would this process work for $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/2}+5^{1/3})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha=\sqrt{3}$ and $\beta=\sqrt[3]{5}$ then $\alpha+\beta$ is a root of:

$$(x-\alpha)^3-5=x^3-3\alpha x^2+3\alpha^2x-\alpha^3-5 = (x^3+9x-5)-3\alpha(x^2+1)$$

Multiply that by $(x^2+9x-5)+3\alpha(x^2+1)$ and you get the integer polynomial:

$$(x^3+9x-5)^2-27(x^2+1)^2$$

More generally, if $\beta$ has minimal polynomial $p(x)$, and $\sqrt{n}\not\in \mathbb Q(\beta)$ then the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{n}+\beta$ is $p(x-\sqrt{n})p(x+\sqrt{n})$.